# Why are there two entrances to the Philosopher's Stone chamber?

Tags: harry-potter, movie

I don't know if anyone else has noticed, but I was rewatching *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone* and really wondered why you can clearly see two passageways leading to the chamber with the mirror. Any thoughts?

[image: Philosopher's Stone chamber.]

Comment: One of those leads to the Philosopher's private bathroom.

Comment: Probably the same as in every dungeon in Skyrim, for easy exit. The flame potions are gone, the door relocked itself and the flying key is on the wrong side etc. You take the other path and open a one-way-door

Comment: @Valorum: Admittedly, often a necessary place for passing the Philosopher's Stone.

Comment: Chances are it's just an artistic pillar in the middle of the stairs.